# Completing Order - Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store

I have built a custom gateway for sage pay form.

The plugin gathers all the data from Store and then posts it off to sagepay in an encrypted string.

User than completes payment on the the sagepay website before being posted back to a specified success URL with an encrypted string attatched. When the string is decoded you can view the order status.

How do i notify cart that the order has been paid for and to log it as complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at other gateways which handle this situation, for example Paypal Express:

https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/blob/master/libraries/merchant/merchant_paypal_express.php

When you build the purchase request, you need to tell the gateway to return the customer to `$this->param('return_url')`. For example, in Paypal this involves:

```
$request['RETURNURL'] = $this->param('return_url');
```

This URL will look something like:

```
https://example.com/index.php?ACT=123&H=abcdef123456
```

This is a special EE action URL, which is passed through to Store. Store looks up the payment hash to see which gateway requested the payment, then automatically loads that gateway, and calls `purchase_return()`. So you need to implement that method on your gateway class:

```
public function purchase_return()
{
    // do something here
}
```

Inside the `purchase_return()` method you should check `$_GET` or `$_POST` for the encrypted string that the gateway sent back to you. Here is another good example of decoding a response and returning the appropriate reply:

https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/blob/master/libraries/merchant/merchant_dps_pxpay.php#L62

Basically, if the transaction is successful you should return something like:

```
return new Merchant_response(Merchant_response::COMPLETE, $response_message_from_gateway, $transaction_id_from_gateway);
```

If the response failed, return something like:

```
return new Merchant_response(Merchant_response::FAILED, $response_message_from_gateway, $transaction_id_if_there_was_one);
```

Then Store will know to update the order accordingly, and will either mark the order as complete and redirect the customer to the success page, or send them back to the checkout to try again.

Comment: #boom! - that worked a treat. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just need to make sure your custom driver extends `Merchant_driver` (or in the case of SagePay, possibly just extend `Merchant_sagepay_base`).

Then I think you just need to make sure you're returning the request at the end of the method for the Merchant Lib and Store to deal with.

```
return $request;
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. I am using 

$this->redirect(self::PROCESS_URL.'?'.$complete);

This redirects to the sage pay URL along with the encrypted string attached. Once sage pay is done it returns to a success url.

There is no API and this process does not happen instantaneously. So when the success page loads, i need some function to fire that completes the order. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: There is the `[store_order_payment_end](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html#store_order_payment_end)` hook but I'm not entirely sure that's what you'd need. I'm sure Adrian can clarify shortly.

Comment: Looking in store_payments.php it looks like it could be all you need with the `process_return` method taking in the same parameters: `process_return($order, $payment)`.

Comment: But how will the store know that payment has been completed? I am posting a encrypted string to sagepay and on completion it is posting one back. Say i decrypt the response, see its all ok what do i then do to get the store to complete the order? Thanks for trying to help :).

Comment: Should the success URL be to a specific script rather than a EE template?